# VLAN tagging on Raspberry Pi not working

Tags: networking

Could you or someone else correct my config?

So my RasPi is connected on a LAN port who has :

- VLAN50 (Severs) as native
- VLAN10 (Trusted)
- VLAN20 (Printers)
- VLAN30 (IoT) as tagged

As a result the RasPi on eth0 gets an IP adress through DHCP pool from VLAN50 (Untagged).

Then I install the vlan package: `apt install vlan`

Then the 8021q module: `echo "8021q" >> /etc/modules & modprobe 8021q`

Then for every VLAN (except 50 since eth0 has this native) I put in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth0.10
static ip_address=10.10.10.5/24
```

Ans as a last step I create a file `vlans` and put it in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`

For every lan (except except 50 since eth0 has this native) I put:

```
auto eth0.10
iface eth0.10 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device eth0
```

If do `hostname -I` I see all ip's, but the VLAN doens't see to work, only when I'm connecting from within the same VLAN.

On my router I have no blocking rules and inter-vlan is working for all other devices.

Thx!

Comment: What does "*VLAN50(Severs) as native*" mean? Does the RasPi see all packages, tagged to VLAN10, VLAN20, VLAN30 and VLAN50? Or does the RasPi see only untagged packages from VLAN50?

Comment: Raspi sees only packges when it's connected with the same VLAN so when I go from 10.10.10.10 to 10.10.10.5 or 10.10.20.10 ro 10.10.20.5..

Comment: What do you mean with "when it's connected with the same VLAN"? And please post the complete config file for interface and vlan and also the routing table.

Answer (score 1):

You are using terms in relation to VLANs that I do not understand, so I will give a short summary how I understand your setup so far.

VLANs are build with additional tags on each ethernet frame. These tags improve the packages with 4 bytes so normal devices cannot read these packages anymore because they do not have the default ethernet frame. They need additional software to be able to read them. One of it is the **8021q** module you are using. In principle it removes the VLAN tag from the package and assign it to a virtual interface. This way the normal ip stack just see normal (untagged) ethernet frames to be compatible with devices that only understand default ethernet frames these tags are heavily removed and added, mainly done by **managed** switches. The switch can be configured to send only untagged packages (it removes and adds the tags) of e.g. VLAN50 through one of its ports. The connected device see default ethernet frames as usual without tags but it is connected to the (virtual) lan VLAN50. There is no need to do anything with ethernet on the device.

The switch can also be configured to send tagged ethernet frames through one of its ports. This is called a trunk line and mainly used for connections between switches. A device like your RasPi will see all ethernet frames with VLAN tags so it needs additional driver to manage it.

It may be possible to send mixed untagged and tagged packages to a device but I have never used it because it doesn't make much sense and I don't know if or how the driver (*8021q*) can manage it. I strongly recommend not to do it, because it complicate things a lost.

Now to your question. You wrote:

> As a result the RasPi on eth0 gets an IP address through DHCP pool from VLAN50 (Untagged).

This is exactly what it do on an untagged port. There is nothing to do with the ethernet connection, in particular to install the **8021q** module. The RasPi works normal with **eth0** connected to VLAN50. The work to connect it to VLAN50 is done by the switch.